# How to run "show interfaces status" to Cisco/Alcatel switch via java (jsch if possible)

Tags: java, ssh

I need run `show interfaces status` to Cisco/Alcatel switch via java (jsch if possible)

I use SSH to access this swith. after I try

```
Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
channel.setInputStream(null);
((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);
channel.setOutputStream(System.out);
InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
channel.connect();
```

I try this (OK if I run manually command in console)

```
Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");
channel.setInputStream(null);
channel.connect();
```

I need connect, send command and record the result of command. If I exec this manually the result is OK. I try my code in a virtual machine and the result is different to a physical switch.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
Channel channel=null;
String result = null;

try
{
            channel = session.openChannel("exec");
            String Command = "show interfaces status";   // Command
            //System.out.println("Command : "+Command);
            ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(Command);
            InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
            byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
            channel.connect();
            if(channel.isConnected())
            {
                //System.out.println("Channel connected");
            }
            while(true)
            {    // geeting the result in this loop
                while(in.available()>0)
                                {
                    int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                    if(i<0)break;
                    result += new String(tmp, 0, i);    // result
                }
                if(channel.isClosed())
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    try{ Thread.sleep(1000); }catch(Exception ee){}
                }
            }
        }
catch(JSchException e)
{
            // your exception message
}
```

Comment: you code is the same of me. `in.available()` is always `0`, so infinity loop

Comment: Always '0' doesn't mean infinity in this code rather it will not enter the loop.

Comment: When no data would come then in.available Will be zero.
Java Doc says "Returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking by the next invocation of a method for this input stream"

Comment: Yes, but `in` do not contain result of command, there is nothing in it and the chanel remains open. The `while(true)` never stop. How to have result of prompt in `InputStream in` ?

Comment: did you test on a physical switch?

Comment: physical switch mean? `switch` statement right ?  
I have tested this code. I think In case of exec mode .. after every command executed channel close it self. My code is working.

Comment: You test on Cisco or Alcatel physical switch?

Comment: I have tested it to get the result of command from remote server (RedHat) using java Jsch.

Comment: yes but on my side it also worked on a remote server but not on a physical switch. This was the main subject of my question.